# SharedPreferences doing math with doubles don't work and there is no putDouble

Tags: java, android, double, sharedpreferences

So I want to + two Doubles but it gives some really weird results.
Here can you see how it looks [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He8GfWer7D8) think it has something to do with plus strings and SharedPreferences not having putDouble. I have tried the last 2 hours to fix it but I cant get it to work can someone help me.
Here is the code:

```
package me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;

import static me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.R.id.brix;
import static me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.R.id.textView;
import static me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.R.id.textView3;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText milkdone;
private EditText brixdone;
private double milkdone2;
private double brixdone2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    milkdone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.milkliter);
    brixdone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.brix);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String MilkDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("MilkDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(MilkDone2Saved)){
        milkdone2 = Double.parseDouble(MilkDone2Saved);
    }
    String BrixDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("BrixDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(BrixDone2Saved)){
        brixdone2 = Double.parseDouble(BrixDone2Saved);
    }
    brixdone.setText(String.valueOf(brixdone2));
    milkdone.setText(String.valueOf(milkdone2));
    milkdone.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String MilkDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("MilkDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(MilkDone2Saved)){
                    milkdone2 = Double.parseDouble(MilkDone2Saved);
                }
                String BrixDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("BrixDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(BrixDone2Saved)){
                    brixdone2 = Double.parseDouble(BrixDone2Saved);
                }
                double test2 = brixdone2 + milkdone2;
                TextView change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                change.setText(String.valueOf(test2));
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }

    });
    brixdone.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String MilkDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("MilkDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(MilkDone2Saved)){
                    milkdone2 = Double.parseDouble(MilkDone2Saved);
                }
                String BrixDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("BrixDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(BrixDone2Saved)){
                    brixdone2 = Double.parseDouble(BrixDone2Saved);
                }
                double test2 = brixdone2 + milkdone2;
                TextView change = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                change.setText(String.valueOf(test2));
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
    };
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        storeDouble("MilkDone2Saved",milkdone);
        storeDouble("BrixDone2Saved",brixdone);

    }
    public void storeDouble(String d, EditText c){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString(d,String.valueOf(c.getText().toString()));
        editor.apply();
}
public void GetDouble(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SavedTotals",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

}
```

It converting from double to string to double (I think).
its supposed do brixdone2 + milkdone2 and its not the right result
EDIT: changed it and now the app crashes with

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:279)
me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.MainActivity.getDouble (MainActivity.java:31)
me.danilkp1234.laerkeholtmilk.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:40)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7174)
```

[Here is the Updated Code that Crashes](https://pastebin.com/raw/Ej4abiNS)

Comment: are you confused about the digits after the decimal point? You need to state more clearly what is supposed to happen vs. what actually happens.

Comment: Your naming conventions stops me to read your question.

Comment: its supposed say brixdone2 + milkdone2

Answer (score 0):

### I'm not sure but problem can be here

String MilkDone2Saved=(prefs.getString("MilkDone2Saved",String.valueOf(milkdone)));

getString return either string associated with *MikeDone2Saved* key and if key not found then default value which is

> String.valueOf(milkdone)

but i thing there will be garbage value to *String.valueOf(milkdone)*  in *onCreate()* so check this once again...